# Batch file that change dns between 2 option

Tags: powershell, batch-file, dns

I'm trying to make a windows 10 batch file that swap my dns from 2 options. The first one is 8.8.8.8 (google dns) and the second one are a custom DNS that allows me to watch US netflix (like 90.90.90.90).

The bash command to change dns is

```
netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver "Ethernet" address=8.8.8.8 index=1
```

the command to check which dns is up and running is:

```
nslookup
```

Now i want to do an IF THEN ELSE that work like this:

```
if (dns == 8.8.8.8) 

then (change them to 90.90.90.90)

else (change them to 8.8.8.8)
```

Even a powershell script is fine

Comment: [5 Utilities for Changing DNS Servers in Windows Reviewed](http://helpdeskgeek.com/free-tools-review/5-utilities-changing-dns-servers-windows-reviewed/)

Comment: See also http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/02/26/how-do-i-query-and-retrieve-dns-information.aspx

Comment: I used to use a little program that ran in the task tray that had predefined Network Settings I could chose from.  I just can't recall the name of the program.  I used it a lot because I worked for rural school district and I used a different static ip address at each school.  If I find it again I will reply back again.  But I am sure you could Google search as well.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
@echo off

set "dns=8.8.8.8"
for /F "skip=1 tokens=2" %%a in ('nslookup^<NUL') do if "%%a" equ "8.8.8.8" set "dns=90.90.90.90"
netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver "Ethernet" address=%dns% index=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically:

```
        # Setup the dos command process information:
    $pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    $pinfo.FileName = "nslookup"
    $pinfo.Arguments = ""
    $pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
    $pinfo.CreateNoWindow = $true
    $pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
    $pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true

    # Start the process:
    $process.Start() | Out-Null

    # Wait a while for the process to do something:
    sleep -Seconds 5

    # If the process is still active kill it:
    if (!$process.HasExited) {
        $process.Kill()
    }

    # get output from stdout and stderr:
    $stdout = $process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    $stderr = $process.StandardError.ReadToEnd()

    # Parse the IP address from the output:
    $regex = [regex] "\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"
    $regex.Matches($stdout) | %{ $Condition = $_.value }

    # Do your dns change based on the output:
    if ($Condition -eq "8.8.8.8")
    {
        "set other dns"
    }
    Else
    {
        "set google dns"
    }
```

Sorry I couldn't mature the answer a bit more; unexpected visitors.

-Edit:

Taking into account some of the comments, and a bug with my regular expression, this might be a more suitable solution:

```
[cmdletbinding()]            
param ([parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)] [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:computername )                        

begin {}            
    process {            
        # get current DNS setting:
        foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {            
            if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -ea 0)
            {            
            try {            
                $Networks = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $Computer -EA Stop | ? {$_.IPEnabled}            
            }
            catch
            {            
                Write-Warning "Error occurred while querying $computer."            
                Continue            
            }            
            foreach ($Network in $Networks)
            {            
                $Condition = $Network.DNSServerSearchOrder;
                break;
            }            
            }            
        }            
        # Do your dns change based on the output:
        if ($Condition -eq "8.8.8.8")
        {
            "set other dns";
        }
        Else
        {
            "set google dns";
        }
    }            

end {}
```

Comment: Why parse text when you can get objects to process easily by using either WMI or the Get-DnsClientServerAddress cmdlet (Windows 8.1 and anove)?

Comment: Because Matteo indicated he was using the nslookup command; but more so because the basic pattern can be re-purposed for a number of administrative tasks that require some if/then/else logic.

Comment: Is this a powershell script? Because the error list is so long if i try to run it on PS that i don't understand if it's just the "guidelines" or an actual script.
Of course i changed the if/then/else part.

Comment: It's a powershell script, the errors are probably permissions related.  By default, for obvious reasons, powershell has limited abilities and you have to set the permissions.  I typically use the 'Windows Powershell ISE to write/debug and you may need to run the powershell short-cut 'as administrator' depending on your local security settings.  One reference:http://www.cyprich.com/2009/04/23/setting-permissions-to-run-powershell-scripts/

Comment: But check the first line for example

    $pinfo = New - Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo

there is a space between new and object that throws an error. Or in the if condition 

     if ($Condition - eq "8.8.8.8")
the - eq have a space. IT should be -eq. 
and when i fix those errors i get this one:
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Desktop\netflixSetDNS.ps1:11 char:1
+ $process.Start() | Out - Null
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
http://i.imgur.com/veT0XTp.jpg

Comment: Not sure about why it fails like that from the command line; however I did check that the second snipped works much better from the command line.  I did have to run the command prompt as an administrator.